# How to call a C function of a complex argument from C++

Tags: c++, complex-numbers

I want to call a C function of a complex argument, declared as

```
double _Complex cerf ( double _Complex z );
```

from C++. The following works:

```
#include<complex.h>
double _Complex z = 1.0;
cerf( z );
```

However, I fail to assign an imaginary part to z:

```
double _Complex z = 1.0 + _Complex_I * 2.0;
```

does not compile under g++: `"unable to find numeric literal operator ‘operator""iF’"`. Other expressions I tried lead to other, similarly cryptic error messages.

Comment: (OT) read "does not compile" as "[does not compute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Does_not_compute)"

Comment: Define `does not compile`. What is the error?

Comment: I have no idea why this was marked as a duplicate of a question about using only C, when this is clearly about mixing C++ and C APIs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ and C is not completely compatible with each other, especially for C99 features, which may or may not present in C++, and complex number is one of them. [C++ and C compatibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B)

If you are using GCC, you can use the flag `-fext-numeric-literals` to enable support for `_Complex`.

[Working example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4304aabb1be39ec6)

Comment: Thanks. Using g++ with `-fext-numeric-literals`, the posted code compiles cleanly.

Comment: Note that the std::complex<> template deliberately has a binary layout making it compatible with _Complex in C99. This means you can substitute one for the other depending on whether you are compiling as C99 or C++11 (or later). See for example: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex
If using the gcc extension you can mix them freely (but not portably) and reinterpret_cast between them.